# How to solve simultaneous exponential equations with polynomial parts?

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation

I have been puzzled at how to simultaneously solve the following equations and before I give up entirely I thought I'd turn to fellow mathematicians first:

$$2^x=3y$$
$$2^y=5x$$

I have graphed both of these and there are two solutions for both variables but I feel I have exhausted all of my own methods to find solutions algebraically. My ability is of a first year Physics undergraduate. Perhaps I have missed a trick, or they don't have enough information on their own, but whatever it is I'd be very grateful for solutions with a method to solve.

Comment: Maybe logs can help you very much

Comment: plugging $y$ you get $$5x=2^{\frac13\cdot2^x}$$ solving it is the only way to go. It has two solutions without a closed form.

Comment: If you could reduce the problem to $\dots=f(x)^{f(x)}$, the solution may be found in terms of the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve that analytically.

Eliminating $y$,

$$5x=2^{2^x/3}.$$

From the plot, you see two real roots, one between $0$ and $0.5$ ($0.2639479321406\cdots$), the other between $3.5$ and $4$ ($3.6521440237168\cdots$).

As you can check,

$$5\cdot 0<2^{1/3},5\cdot0.5>2^{\sqrt2/3},\\
5\cdot3.5>2^{8\sqrt2/3},5\cdot4<2^{16/3}.$$

The derivative seems monotonic, confirming a single extremum hence two roots.

---

Taking the logarithm twice and rearranging,

$$\ln(2)x=\ln(\ln(x)+\ln(5))-\ln(\ln(2))+\ln(3).$$

The extremum is found by canceling the derivative

$${\ln(2)}=\frac{\dfrac1x}{\ln(x)+\ln(5)},$$ 
or

$$5x\ln(5x)=\frac5{\ln(2)}.$$

The function $5x\ln(5x)$ is monotonous increasing for $5x>\frac1e$ and there is a single solution.

Answer (score 1):

Equations that mix exponential and polynomial terms, can't in general be solved. There are a few special cases, but this doesn't appear like one of them.

We can manipulate the equations a bit, $$2^x = 3y$$ $$2^y = 5x$$ gives $x = 2^y/5$ and $2^{\frac{2^y}{5}} = 3y$.

Thankfully, $x$ is a 1-1 function of $y$, so once $y$ is determined, $x$ is determined simply by plugging in $y$.

To solve the last equation: $2^{\frac{2^y}{5}} = 3y$, there are a few methods you can use to derive an approximate solution. The most straight forward method is to graph $f(y) = 2^{\frac{2^y}{5}} - 3y$ and estimate it's zeros to obtain an estimate of $y$.

If you want something you can do by hand, it will take longer, you can try to implement Newton's method. Newton's method is an iterative method, so you can achieve more and more accurate estimates through repeated application.

First you make a guess at the solution, say $y=1$. Then you take the tangent line of $f$ at $y=1$ and follow that line to zero. This zero becomes your first estimate, and your next guess.

To wit,

$$f'(y) = \frac{2^y}{5} 2^{2^y/5} - 3$$

$$f'(1) = \frac{2}{5} \cdot 2^{2/5} - 3$$

$$f(1) = 2^{2/5} - 3$$

and $$L(y) = (\frac{2}{5} \cdot 2^{2/5} - 3)(y-1) + ( 2^{2/5} - 3).$$

Thus $y_2$ solves $$L(y_2) = 0 = (\frac{2}{5} \cdot 2^{2/5} - 3)(y_2-1) + ( 2^{2/5} - 3)$$ and $$y_2 = \frac{-( 2^{2/5} - 3)}{(\frac{2}{5} \cdot 2^{2/5} - 3)} + 1$$ is our first guess at a solution for $y$.

---

Since there are two zeros to this function (we can see this by looking at the graph) the choice of initialization of Newton's method (ours was $y=1$ here) will lead to convergence to a different zero (if it does converge).

Graphically, it appears that $y\approx 0.40$ and $y\approx 4.19$ are solutions.

Comment: I see, thank you. How is it so that in general these can't be solved? After several juggling about of the terms I decided to try solving 2^x-3log_2(5x)=0 in a similar fashion to the way x^2-x=0 is solved through factorisation although I found no way to do it.

Comment: The issue comes down to how we can find roots of polynomials. The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that every polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $n \ge 1$ has $n$ complex zeros (possibly with some zeros repeated). This is what guarantees the roots, and the long division algorithm can be used to factor the polynomials.

Comment: For equations involving more complicated functions, there is not a direct method of inverting equations like $2^y = 3y$. That doesn't mean there is no solutions, but there is not a systematic approach to finding exact solutions. Sometimes these things can be solved, for instance $2^{y-1} = y$ has the solution $y=1$, but that is done by luck and inspection.

Comment: This might make things a little clearer. Suppose we want to solve $e^x + x = 0$. If instead of $e^x$ we had a polynomial, $p(x)$, then we would search for the zeros of the polynomial $p(x)+x$. Looking at $e^x$ as a power series we see that we are looking for a solution to $$1+2x + (1/2) x^2 + (1/6) x^3 + (1/24) x^4 + \cdots = 0.$$

Comment: The truth is the only equations we can solve systematically really are polynomial equations. Even when we have an equation like $e^{2x} - 2 e^x + 1 =0$, we make a mental substitution of $u = e^{x}$ to make it a polynomial and find $$(e^x - 1)^2 = 0.$$

Comment: You have been exceptionally helpful, thank you very much I understand now. I feel a little foolish though; in all honesty I've been trying to work this out or a couple of days but at least being told it's impossible is better than pointing out an obvious method I had missed. It is interesting we have not devised a method for systematically solving this when the exponential function has been with mathematics or so long. Again, thank you for your help.